# Is it possible to use a model in it's own factory in a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, factory, faker

My team is building a project using laravel for the server code. Early on we were going to use models to manage some of the images used in the project, but we didn't have the images from the client yet. So we built out the models and used a laravel factory and faker to create fake images for testing.

A month later (and many test cases later) we have the actual images from the client. I added the images to the project, created structural database seeders to populate the data needed for the database, and wrote out unit tests for the model to confirm it works.

The issue is that now some of the tests are failing because the factory we're using for the image model still uses factory and faker. Anywhere where we need to look for a specific file using the model we get fails from the fake data provide by faker.

I thought "well that's fine, I can just switch out the fake data in the factory for randomized data from the actual model". The problem I'm running into now is that when I try to use the actual model within the factory function, the model class only gets provided as a factory:

[image: getting the class of the model]

I know there's a good reason for this happening behind the scenes, I'm just wondering if there's a way of getting around it. If it's possible to use the actual model in the factory it would prevent me from having to rewrite a *lot* of test cases to swap out the factory for the actual model. It also seems like this would be a really convenient way of being able to do feature testing for items that you know will exist but don't have the actual assets for yet.

Is there a way around this or should I plan on buckling down and refactoring my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory exists to generate a model on demand using *fake* data — not necessarily from faker but data that doesn't represent an entity that already exists. You are attempting to create factories that depend on the database having been populated with real data but if you have a database with real data that you need to test against then you should use that data directly. Your approach would give tests a dependency on real data which would now need to be distributed to all developers and build services.

Populating your database with a fixed set of data for testing should be done using [Database Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding). At the start of the development you should create a database seeder (which can use factories) to populate your database with fake data, then once you obtain the real data you can add an additional database seeder (or populate the database directly from outside of Laravel if necessary). This approach means that your application can be tested without any concern for whether the data is real or not, and you'd continue to be able to use factories as they're intended to be used.

The unfortunate conclusion here is that if you wish for your tests to be resilient you're going to need to refactor.

If you absolutely must use factories with real data then you can [create your own faker provider](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#faker-internals-understanding-providers) that has fallbacks for if the data does not exist.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I'm using seeders for populating data and calling seeders from the tests for most items. I guess my approach was a bit backwards (using factories for specific models and swapping them out with models populated by structural seeders later vs starting with models using fake seeders and swapping them out with structural seeders later). Def good to know for next time. I've already done the refactor and it wasn't too bad, but def don't want to do that on the next project. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you declare the class object as the Faker class is being passed as a parameter within the factory declaration, you should be able to use it within the factory itself. I might be wrong though, I believe it happens that way because the factory itself is a function call, so any parameters used need to be declared before hand within its function() call.

If I recall correctly, if you do this:

> $factory->define(App\models\AreaOfAffectMap::class, function(AOA $AOA) {...

It should work.

Comment: Mind you, I have no idea if it wouldn't work because faker is initialized as a singleton, I have had a fair deal of issues trying to port factories myself.

Comment: Hmm, gave it a try and still get fails. It looks like the type check for AOA causes an issue because the AOA class gets passed into the closure as a factory :/ I tried removing the parameter all together (since faker isn't actually needed) and I'm back to the original error. Good suggestion though, it was def a logical step to try out.

Comment: Have you tried declaring $map outside of the factory method call, and then passing it inside as a value? EDIT: Mind you, it might still fail since it expects a factory object. Not super sure what else you could do.